# Linear Algebra Rank

Tags: linear-algebra

> If $A$ is an $n\times n$ matrix and $A\vec{x} = \vec{b}$ has exactly one solution for each $\vec{b} \in \mathbb{R}^n$, then $\text{rk}(A) = n$.

Can you help me get started on this question? So far, I'm leaning towards the path of $A\vec{x}=0$. And $0$ falls under any $\mathbb{R}^n$. But if the rank is $0$, then it must be a null vector. So I'm guessing it's false.

Is this true or false?

Answer (score 1):

Two solutions:

Solution 1) If rank($A$)< $n$ then by rank nullity theorem, dim$N(A)$> 0. But $A0=0$ and we know $Ax=b$ has unique solution.

Solution 2) Take $b=e_i$ where $e_i$ form the standard basis of $\mathbb{R}^n$. Then we get unique solutions $x_i$ i.e. $Ax_i=e_i$. Let $B=[x_1, x_2, ... ,x_n]$. Then $AB=I$, and so $A$ is invertible, and hence rank$(A)=n$

Answer (score 0):

**This statement is true.**  Why?  Here's an outline:

If there is one solution to the system $A\vec{x} = \vec{b}$, then the columns of $A$ are independent.  (I believe this is typically shown by contradiction.)

$\text{rk}(A)$ is defined as the dimension of the row space of $A$, which is equivalent to the dimension of the column space of $A$.  (This is typically given as a theorem... I forget how to prove the two dimensions are equal, but that should be a fairly well-known proof.)

Since all $n$ columns are independent, the basis for $RS(A)$ has $n$ elements. Thus, $\text{rk}(A) = n$.